# Uninitialized constant Contact (NameError) when trying to add a record

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite, activerecord, uninitialized-constant

Model contact.rb:

```
class Contact < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :phone
end
```

Test.rb:

```
Contact.create({:name => "Josh", :phone => "123-456789"})
```

When I run test.rb from terminal I'm receiving the error:

> lib/tasks/test.rb:1:in `': uninitialized constant Contact
>   (NameError)

database.yml:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000
```

I believe this is a trivial question. I've searched this forum, but it didn't give any clue on this.

Let me know if I have to input additional information to make it clear.

Comment: How do you run the test?

Comment: from terminal. I'm planning to make it a scheduled task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot simply run `ruby lib/tasks/test.rb` because the Rails environment will not be loaded. To fix this, you need to use a rake task.

You first have to rename your file `lib/tasks/test.rb` to `lib/tasks/test.rake`.

Then, you need to add this to `test.rake`.

```
namespace :contact do # This is not require. It can work without having to nest your task within a namespace.
  desc 'Add contact'
  task 'add' => [:environment]  do #Here, we specify we want to load the environment
    Contact.create({:name => "Josh", :phone => "123-456789"})
  end
end
```

Then, run `rake -T` which will list all the available tasks.

You will be able to launch your task with `rake contact:add`.

To schedule your task to be run at a specific time, you might want to take a look at the [Whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) gem.

Hope it helps.

Comment: thanks, I'm aware of the Whenever gem. When I run following your advice above I've received the error: rake aborted!
uninitialized constant Inflector
/home/askar/Dropbox/rails_studio/sqltest/config/environment.rb:7:in `<top (required)>'
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require'
/home/askar/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p429/gems/railties-3.2.13/lib/rails/application.rb:103:in `require_environment!'
... I couldn't put all the error message as it is long.

Comment: What do you have in config/environment.rb ? Any custom statement ?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I had a custom statement there, before I made this post. Once I've delete it, it worked. Thanks a lot! :)